# split canvas (dynamically) screens based on the drop down selection for fabricjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

i am trying to create split screens in fabric js for example 1, 2, 4, 8,16

based on the drop selection screen has to split.

Here is my [Current code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8tqgr)  where I can able to upload images.

and if i click the images it will show as preview

I was not aware how to change screen based on the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @spring

actually what exactly i want is 

1) by default my preview window will be in 1 full screen 
2) when i select the drop down and change to 2 screen my preview window has to split in to two side
like that 1 , 2, 4, 8 ,16  when it is 16 16 canvas has to be there

Comment: It is still very much unclear

Comment: @Gitesh Sharma is tht possible can we please connect so i can explain you in detail

Comment: Sure @Mr.M, BTW I checked your other questions, if there is any ques still left unanswered, then let em know.

Comment: @GiteshSharma yes still other question also unanswered

Comment: What you have on that link (current code | https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmlfmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) looks nothing like that image

Comment: @HelderSepulveda if you see ere there is a drop down mounting 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8tqgr in current scenario where we can upload the image 

the screen shot which i put is for reference please don't close the question

Comment: That link is different than the one you have on the question ... please edit your question to make it clear avoid long discussions on the comments ... and questions with a bounty can not be closed

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yes i updated the new link

Comment: Update the link and make it clear, you added clarifications in the comments that are not in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230273/discussion-between-helder-sepulveda-and-mr-m).

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I am there in chat window could you please join

Comment: @HelderSepulveda can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into this, I have updated your Stackblits and it's working.

https://angular-ivy-qbqu1r.stackblitz.io

On selection of screens dropdown - Canvases are getting generated

Need to select by clicking on canvas to add images after uploading or add text on selected canvas

removed canvas generation from image click to avoid multiple canvas generation